# counterexample: degree of representation $\leq$ index of normal subgroup

Tags: representation-theory, finite-groups

if I have a finite group $G$ with an abelian normal subgroup $N$  and an irreducible representation $\pi$ of $G$ over $K$. Then I know, that $deg(\pi) \leq [G:N]$, if $K$ has positive characteristic and is a splitting field for $G$. My professor claimed (without a proof), that this is also true if I take $K=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Why should it work? I mean, $K$ must not be a splitting field here? Or are there any counterexamples?

I tried to get a counterexample for $G=\mathbb{Z}/p'\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $gcd(p,p')=1$. You should get here, that the dimension of an irreducible $K(G)$-module is 1 or 2. But I don't get a result.

regards, Khanna

Comment: Not yet. This theorem we did not have. Maybe that is the reason, why there wasn't a proof in class. I am going to read about it. Thank you

Comment: If what your professor said was correct, then all meta-abelian groups would be supersolvable. :-) C3 (and its incarnation A4) is the smallest counterexample, but my answer goes along with your idea of using dihedral groups.

Comment: You may hear the term “absolutely irreducible $K$-module” for a module where $K$ is close enough to being a splitting field (it is a splitting field for that module, maybe not for every module). If $\pi$ is absolutely irreducible, then the theorem holds. In my example, the representations are irreducible, but not absolutely irreducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counterexamples** are pretty common. Your idea of taking a dihedral group $G$ is good. For instance, consider a faithful irreducible representation of the dihedral group of order 10 over a field of size 3. Obviously<sup>[1]</sup> it has a faithful irreducible representation, so we just want to figure out its dimension.

The dimension is not 1, because $\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}\GL(1,3)$ has order $2 < 10$. The dimension is not even 2 since $\GL(2,3)$ has order $48 \neq 0 \mod 10$, so Lagrange's theorem shows that $G$ has no faithful representation of dimension 2 over a field of size 3. In fact the explicit matrices<sup>[2]</sup> show that dimension 4 is large enough, and a consideration of eigenvalues shows that dimension 4 is minimal.

[1] Every normal subgroup is the kernel of a representation, and since the field has order coprime to the group, every representation is semi-simple, so only the irreducible representations in the representation matter (not their multiplicities). Since $G$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup, it must have a faithful irreducible representation in order for the trivial subgroup to be a kernel.

[2] Also, I give some explicit matrices in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175117/definition-of-k-conjugacy-classes). The question and answer use the Frobenius automorphism and traces to find minimal dimensions of faithful irreducible representations.

### Smallest counterexample

Let $G$ be cyclic of order 3, and let $K=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ be a field of order 2. Let $N=G$ and check that $N$ is an abelian normal subgroup of index $[G:N]=1$. However, $\GL(1,K)$ has order 1, and so every representation of a group of dimension 1 over $K$ is the trivial representation. However, $G$ has more than just the trivial representation: it has an irreducible representation of dimension 2:
$$ a = \begin{bmatrix} . & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \in \GL(2,K)$$
It is not reducible, since being the direct sum of two one-dimensional representations over $K$ is the same as being the direct sum of two trivial representations over $K$, is the same as every group element mapping to the identity matrix. In particular, here is an irreducible representation $\pi$ such that $\deg(\pi)=2 > [G:N]=1$.

The only smaller groups are $G$ of order 1 and 2, and in those cases all irreducible representations over every field are dimension 1, so there is no problem.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like a difficult counterexample, but you explained it really good. In the answer of the other question, it sounds like an interesting example for simple $KG$-modules in positive characteristic. But I just don't see, what the number of all the simple modules is? You wrote, there is just one faithful repr., but are there other irred. repr., which are not faithful?

Comment: @Khanna: yes. A dihedral group of order $10$ over a field of size $q \in \{3,13\}$ has exactly 3 irreducible representations: the trivial (everything goes to [1]), the sign (reflections go to [-1], rotations go to [1]), and the faithful irreducible.

Comment: And in general (for the dihedral goup): Are there always just the 2 one-dim. irreducible representations and the other are faithful irreducible representations?

Comment: @Khanna: yes exactly. The number of faithful irreducibles is always between $1$ and $(p-1)/2$ (a divisor of $(p-1)/2$ even) and has to do with the multiplicative order of $q$ mod $p$ (or more exactly the size of the subgroup $\langle q, -1 \rangle \leq \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. I've only thought about this when $p$ is an odd prime, so check it for non-prime and evens, but I don't think the general case is too much different (presumably $p-1$ becomes $\phi(n)$, etc.).

Comment: It sound like a good topic for a bachelor thesis. Thank you for your inspiration :)

Comment: Oops! I misread the question. I thought the question WAS working over a spiltting fieed of positive characteristic. As it stands, the claim that it works in the prime field case can be false even when $G = N.$ Take $G = N$ to be the cyclic group of order $3$ and $p= 2$ and $\tau$ to be a faithful irreducible, which has degree $2$ . Very sorry for misleading you Khanna (and, now I read Jack's answer carefully, I see that he already had this example!!

Comment: No problem! Maybe I could use Clifforf's theory later anyway