# Characters of elements under every representation equal implies conjugacy

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules

> If $G$ is a group, suppose that for every $G$-module $V$ we have
>   $$\chi_V(g_1)=\chi_V(g_2).$$ 
>   How can I be sure $g_1$ and $g_2$ are conjugate in $G$?

Its easy to the reverse implication; that is $\chi_V(g)=\chi_V(hgh^{-1})\ \forall h\in G$. But how do I know $\chi_V$ won't map non-conjugates to the same element in $GL(V)$?

Thanks

Comment: Is $G$ finite here? If so, this is a standard result in the representation theory of finite groups. You need to show that characters form an orthonormal basis of the space of class functions, and then consider a suitable class function.

Comment: The relevant hypotheses here are $G$ finite, ground field algebraically closed (actually, containing the $|G|$-th roots of unity is enough) and characteristic zero. With these conditions, see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/189900/448

Comment: I really didn't think this was deep enough to depend on the finiteness of $G$ or that $V$ was over an algebraically-closed field. Really thought this would be a much more simple idea. Nevertheless, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here are counterexamples showing what happens when we drop any of the hypotheses listed by David Speyer in the comments.

**$G$ finite:** The key point here is that characters are only defined for $V$ finite-dimensional, and it is possible to write down infinite groups $G$ which have no nontrivial finite-dimensional representations whatsoever. See, for example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358104/nonabelian-group-with-all-irreducible-representations-one-dimensional/358126#358126).

**Ground field containing the $|G|^{th}$ roots of unity:** Suppose we work over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $G = C_3 = \{ 1, \omega, \omega^2 \}$. Over $\mathbb{R}$, aside from the trivial representation there is only one other $2$-dimensional irreducible representation (coming from the embedding of $C_3$ into $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$), and this representation $V$ satisfies $\chi_V(\omega) = \chi_V(\omega^2)$. Maschke's theorem still holds here, so every representation is a direct sum of these, and it follows that characters don't separate $\omega$ and $\omega^2$.

**Ground field of characteristic zero:** Suppose we work over a field of characteristic $3$, and let $G = C_3$ again. If $\rho$ is a finite-dimensional representation, then

$$0 = 1 - \rho(\omega^3) = 1 - \rho(\omega)^3 = (1 - \rho(\omega))^3$$

hence $1 - \rho(\omega)$ is nilpotent, hence it has trace $0$. The same is true for $\rho(\omega^2)$, so characters don't separate any of the elements of $G$!

The first and third counterexamples both come, in some sense, from the failure of Maschke's theorem (more formally, the failure of the [group algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_algebra) to be [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module)), whereas the second comes from the failure of representations to [split](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_field).

Comment: still up at this point....