# proof of "number of conjugacy classes equals number of inequivalent irreducible representation"

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

There are related discussions:
[About the number of inequivalent irreducible representations of a finite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531868/about-the-number-of-inequivalent-irreducible-representations-of-a-finite-group)

[Relationship between number of conjugacy classes and number of irreducible representations of a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408481/relationship-between-number-of-conjugacy-classes-and-number-of-irreducible-repre)

[Estimate the Number of Conjugacy Classes of $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676087/estimate-the-number-of-conjugacy-classes-of-g)

I am a beginner of representation theory or algebra. There are many discussions related to the title here; however, just application of it. Actually I will apply this theorem to my study, but I am interested the proof.

Is there any lecture or link that has proof of it?  or just the intuition behind this is fine.

Comment: This is proved in every textbook on representation theory. It is a basic result.

Comment: Adding to the comment of Derek, why do you say that these are just applications? Those questions also have answers with proofs o the statement.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I can see why equality happens in complex field. However, how do you show, in general, that only $\leq$ holds in arbitrary field (group is still finite)? I cannot find it in any book.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can I ask you the same question above?