# Representation of abelian groups over rationals

Tags: representation-theory

In my representation theory of finite groups, I learnt about complex representation of abelian groups. Now I am looking for references to study representations of abelian groups over rationals. Possibly here : [Representation theory over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676303/representation-theory-over-mathbbq) a question in similar lines has been asked few years ago. But I am unable to find the material in Curtis-Reiner as mentioned in one of the answers. Can someone give me a concise reference for studying the topic I mentioned above? Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you find it  in the second volume of the two-volume work of Curtis and Reiner? I think the answers given there are really good. Of course, you need to start reading Curtis and Reiner first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I surfed through it once again and found the chapter on Rationality Questions. But actually I was looking for a more readable resource, not exactly this one. Can you let me know such a source?